# Fetch multiple separated objects.

Tags: php, database, mysqli

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM friend JOIN user ON friend.uId=user.uId WHERE friend.friendId= ?");

$stmt->bind_param('s',$userId);

if($stmt->execute()){
    $user = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($obj = $user->fetch_object()) {
         $friends[] = $obj;
    }
    echo json_encode($friends);
}
```

my above code produced an array

```
[{"uId":"2","firstName":"Gem","lastName":"Tang"},{"uId":"3","firstName":"James","lastName":"Lebron"}]
```

but I wish it could be 2 object instead.

Comment: It is an array of objects.

Comment: @RPM I don't want that, how to extract them from array?

Comment: Why don't you want that?

Comment: @RPM I want it seperately for later use.

Comment: go on, show us that later use.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I must extract objects from above array first

Comment: ... and you don't want it. All right, show us the code where you want to use your objects without an array

Comment: I want to push it into another array. I could be [{},[{},{}]] where I want is this : [{},{},{}]

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of objects with length 2. Using JavaScript you can traverse it like this.

```
var o = [{"uId":"2","firstName":"Gem","lastName":"Tang"},{"uId":"3","firstName":"James","lastName":"Lebron"}];

for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
  var row = o[i];
  console.log(row.firstName);
}
```

Comment: javascript? I thought I use PHP tag?

Answer (score -1):

in the while loop:

**You could either use foreach:**

```
$object = new stdClass();
foreach ($obj as $key => $value)
{
    $object->$key = $value;
}
$friends[$obj['uId']] = $object;
```

**or by the json functions:**

```
$friends[$obj['uId']] = json_decode(json_encode($obj), FALSE);
```

Comment: I guessed so, but I left ahint to the json_decode to get an object while decoding. As well as adding the id to the created array of object to get "separated" objects as well as easy to access to identify the objects in the resulting array.